# Как написать свое правило для PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

Нужно как-то научить PhpStorm анализировать мой код и сообщать об описанных мной проблемах в коде.

Например:
 Мы создаем транзакцию,

```
$transaction = beginTransaction();
```

пишем код, сохраняем, обновляем у удаляем данные...
В конце делаем `$transaction->commit();` или `$transaction->rollBack();`

Я хочу сделать так, что бы в случае, если в методе есть запуск транзакции, то PhpStrom должен меня уведомлять о том, что я обязан сделать `$transaction->commit();` и `$transaction->rollBack();`

Можно ли сделать такое?

Буду благодарен за любую подсказку в какую сторону копать!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем случае такую проблему можно решить написав собственный плагин. В нем необходимо создать [инспекцию](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/code_inspections.html), которая для каждой функции будет проверять ее поток управления обходя его из конца в начало. Если в процессе обхода выяснится, что существует ветвь, в которой не вызывается соответствующий "закрывающий" метод, "открывающий" метод должен быть подсвечен как ошибочный.

Comment: Спасибо! Вы подтвердили путь, в котором я сомневался.